# ERROR: While executing gem ... (TypeError) incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, macos-mojave

I encountered this issue when I run `bundle install` with Ruby version 2.4.4 and macOS Mojave:

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.5
Installing nokogiri 1.8.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please
make sure `pkg-config` is installed.
```

So I ran

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

But then when I run `gem install nokogiri` I got the following output:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 60.33 given
```

I tried to set my `cookies_serializer` to `:hybrid`:

```rb
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :hybrid
```

But nothing worked.

Is there a way to fix this? I cannot even run my Rails server right now.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Thanks to Morgan Jarry answer, this is what worked for me :

I checked my current sources and indeed they were outdated :

```
gem sources
```

It printed

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
http://gems.rubyforge.org/
http://gems.github.com
```

So I ran this script to remove them and replaced them with https://rubygems.org/

```
gem sources -r  http://gems.rubyforge.org/
gem sources -r http://gems.github.com
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 25):

Try removing your `~/.gemrc`. I had the same problem on Mojave and this solve my problem.

Comment: I'd like to add some nuance to this answer: `~/.gemrc` contained a referce use rubyforge as a source. This was relevant 10 years ago, but these days gems live on rubygems.org, so you should have a reference to have `https://rubygems.org` as source instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Morgan ! I checked my current sources, they were outdated, so I removed them and replaced them with https://rubygems.org. Then I was able to install nokogori and run bundle install without any problem.

Comment: removing your .gemrc is **** NOT **** the solution. In fact a .gemrc can have a number of helpful controls like setting `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc` :: the correct naswer to this question is the one with more votes below.

Answer (score 9):

You have to remove all the gem sources you have and add https://rubygems.org/ instead. Note that http://gems.rubyforge.org/ and http://gems.github.com are permanently dead and should be removed. You can list your sources by running:

```
gem sources
```

You should get something like this:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

//gems.rubyforge.org/
//gems.github.com
```

1) Delete all sources:

```
gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org/
gem sources -r http://gems.github.com
```

2) Add the right source:

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helped, I had http://gemcutter.org setup, removing which my problem went away

Answer (score 2):

for me just browser cookie cleanup fixed all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31143450)

Comment: This absolutely answers the question. While it could be wordier, so to speak, it's the right answer. After upgrading to macOS 13.1 I ran into this problem in an app that I sometimes have to go between ruby 2.7.5 and 3.1.2 based on a hotfix to an older version of the app. My gem sources were correct but it was the cookies. Cleared them and all good.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, server was responding well in one `branchA` while failing in `branchB` into the same project.

**Solution:**

- Clear browser cache
- Restart server
- Hard refresh browser

That worked for me.

**Possible root cause:**
Rails version was updated in particular branch
In `branchA` it was `Rails 6.0.4`
while in `branchB` it was `Rails 6.1.7.2`

It may also help you!!!